# Is it possible to Get list of SyncUser as Administrator

Tags: realm

I would like to know if it is possible to get the list of SyncUser as administrator ?

I tries something like this :

```
public class AdministrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RealmConfiguration config;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_administration);
    SyncConfiguration syncConfiguration = new SyncConfiguration.Builder().

    config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);

    Collection<SyncUser> users = SyncUser.all();
    List<String> identities = new ArrayList<>();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        identities = users.stream().map(SyncUser::getIdentity).collect(Collectors.toList());
        identities.forEach(System.out::println);
    }else{
        for(SyncUser u : users){
            identities.add(u.getIdentity());
            Log.i("TEST",u.getAccessToken() + "_" +u.getIdentity());
        }
    }


}
}
```

But when i dit that, i have only one user, the one i just connected. 
This user is admin (on the Realm object Server)

So my question is : There is a way to do it ?

Sincerely,

Comment: The current API doesn't have a call for obtain that information. You could get the information from  the management Realm (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#management-realm). RMP is still in beta and we are eager to learn from the community :-) You are welcome to create an issue at https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform and describe your use case.

Comment: I follow you advice, and open a "issue" https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/89